# Simplify trigonometric equation knowing that $\sin(a)=n \sin(b)$

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry, parametric-functions

I was working on a problem involving trigonometry. I used *Mathematica* to help me in solving it. I ended up with this formula:

```
-(1/R) Csc[a - 2 b] (R Cos[a - 2 b] - R (Cos[a - 2 b] - Cot[2 a - 2 b] Sin[a - 2 b]))*
 (-R + R Sin[a - 2 b] - (R^2 Cos[a - 2 b] Sin[a - 2 b])/(R Cos[a - 2 b] - 
      R (Cos[a - 2 b] - Cot[2 a - 2 b] Sin[a - 2 b])))
```

And I know that $\sin a = n\times\sin b $ where $n$ is a real number. After this I expanded the formula using `TrigExpand` that generated a very large output. I want to know how I can replace all trigonometric functions that contains $b$ so at the end I have a formula that contains just $n$ and trigonometric functions that have $a$.

Comment: I'm sorry I broke the expression when editing your post, now it's fixed. I will delete my comments. Although I now wonder why you feel the need to use `TrigExpand` while it works fine without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

This makes everything b-dependent:

```
 Map[TrigExpand, expr] /. {Sin[a] -> n*Sin[b], 
   Cos[a] -> Sqrt[1 - n^2*Sin[b]^2]} // Simplify

(*  -((R Csc[b] (n - n^3 Cos[2 b] + 
       Cos[b] Sqrt[4 - 2 n^2 + 2 n^2 Cos[2 b]] + 
       Sqrt[4 - 2 n^2 + 2 n^2 Cos[2 b]] Cos[3 b] - 
       n^2 Sqrt[4 - 2 n^2 + 2 n^2 Cos[2 b]] Cos[3 b] - 3 n Cos[4 b] + 
       2 n^3 Cos[4 b] + 
       n^2 Sqrt[4 - 2 n^2 + 2 n^2 Cos[2 b]] Cos[5 b] - n^3 Cos[6 b] + 
       n^2 Sin[b] + n Sqrt[4 - 2 n^2 + 2 n^2 Cos[2 b]] Sin[2 b] - 
       n^2 Sin[3 b]))/(2 (n Cos[2 b] - 
       Cos[b] Sqrt[4 - 2 n^2 + 2 n^2 Cos[2 b]]) ((-2 + n^2) Cos[b] + 
       n (Cos[2 b] Sqrt[4 - 2 n^2 + 2 n^2 Cos[2 b]] - n Cos[3 b]))))  *)
```

The same to make it a-dependent:

```
    Map[TrigExpand, expr] /. {Sin[b] -> n^-1*Sin[a], 
   Cos[b] -> Sqrt[1 - n^-2*Sin[a]^2]} // Simplify

(*   (R Csc[a] (-1 + (3 - 4 n^2 + 2 n^4) Cos[2 a] - 
     Sqrt[2] n Cos[a] Sqrt[(-1 + 2 n^2 + Cos[2 a])/n^2] + 
     2 Sqrt[2] n Sqrt[(-1 + 2 n^2 + Cos[2 a])/n^2] Cos[3 a] - 
     2 Sqrt[2] n^3 Sqrt[(-1 + 2 n^2 + Cos[2 a])/n^2] Cos[3 a] - 
     3 Cos[4 a] + 4 n^2 Cos[4 a] - 
     Sqrt[2] n Sqrt[(-1 + 2 n^2 + Cos[2 a])/n^2] Cos[5 a] + 
     Cos[6 a] - 3 n^2 Sin[a] + 2 n^4 Sin[a] - 
     Sqrt[2] n^3 Sqrt[(-1 + 2 n^2 + Cos[2 a])/n^2] Sin[2 a] + 
     n^2 Sin[3 a]))/(2 (-1 + n^2 + Cos[2 a] - 
     Sqrt[2] n Cos[a] Sqrt[(-1 + 2 n^2 + Cos[2 a])/
      n^2]) ((-1 + 2 n^2) Cos[a] - 
     Sqrt[2] n Cos[2 a] Sqrt[(-1 + 2 n^2 + Cos[2 a])/n^2] + Cos[3 a]))    *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = -(1/R) Csc[
    a - 2 b] (R Cos[a - 2 b] - 
     R (Cos[a - 2 b] - Cot[2 a - 2 b] Sin[a - 2 b]))*(-R + 
     R Sin[a - 
        2 b] - (R^2 Cos[a - 2 b] Sin[a - 2 b])/(R Cos[a - 2 b] - 
        R (Cos[a - 2 b] - Cot[2 a - 2 b] Sin[a - 2 b]))) // Simplify
```

> R Csc[2 (a - b)] (Cos[2 (a - b)] + Sin[a])

```
rules = Solve[Sin[a] == n*Sin[b], b]
```

> {{b -> ConditionalExpression[
>            Pi - ArcSin[Sin[a]/n] + 
>              2*Pi*C[1], Element[C[1], 
>              Integers]]},     {b -> ConditionalExpression[
>            ArcSin[Sin[a]/n] + 2*Pi*C[1], 
>            Element[C[1], Integers]]}}

```
expr2 = expr /. rules //
  FullSimplify[#, Element[C[1], Integers]] &
```

> {R Csc[2 (a + ArcCsc[n Csc[a]])] (Cos[2 (a + ArcCsc[n Csc[a]])] + 
>       Sin[a]),   R Csc[2 (a + ArcSec[n Csc[a]])] (Cos[2 (a + ArcSec[n Csc[a]])] - 
>       Sin[a])}